# Parse error syntax error, unexpected 'type' (T_STRING)

Tags: xampp, notepad++

I have this in my php.17

```
echo "<script type ='text/javascript'>
function delayer(){
    window.location = 'peoplelist.html'
}
</script>";
```

However, computer reply this to me 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'type' (T_STRING) line 17, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and add a ; to the end of your text in your JS function

```
<?php
echo "function delayer(){ window.location = 'peoplelist.html'; }";
?>
```

Comment: after I edit it, th error now is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION) in on line 17

Comment: I have tried to my above code and it works perfectly, It must be something wrong with another part of your code, can you tell me what line 17 is?

Comment: echo "<script type = 'text/javascript'>function delayer()